# Topological/metric space formed by behaviors of distributed system: Safety and Liveness

Tags: distributed-systems, automated-theorem-proving, tlaplus

In the book **[A Science of Concurrent Programs](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/science.pdf?back-link=learning.html#science)** Leslie Lamport describes alternative way how to look at **safety** and **liveness** properties in distributed algorithms.

> **A.5 Another Way to Look at Safety and Liveness**
> This section provides a different view of safety and liveness based on viewing
> behavior predicates as sets of behaviors. This view was first recognized by
> Gordon Plotkin. I find that it helps me understand safety and liveness. To
> understand it, we first need some more math.

They build a metric space where distance between behaviors is defined as $\delta(x, y) = 1/(1 + commonPrefixLength(x, y))$

Where can I read about this topological/metric space?

I am interested, in particular:

1. What would be the open sets? All behaviors starting with the finit prefixes?
2. What would be a closed set? In my understanding, open set will be also closed. Given an open set $U$ of behaviors starting with prefix `a,b,c`, then any behavior outside of this set, for example, `a,b,x,...` will belong to another open set, and therefore will not be a limit point of $U$.
3. What would be a dense set? I think dense set will be a set consisting of all behaviors ending with stuttering steps - infinite tails where state of the system does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard reference for the topological characterisation is [Bowen Alpern and Fred B. Schneider. Defining liveness. *Information Processing Letters*, 21(4): 181–185, October 1985](https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(85)90056-0).

One notable difference to Lamport's characterisation is that Alpern & Schneider don't insist on stuttering closure. If I recall correctly, if one wanted to characerise both versions of safety properties via closures, one would say that a Lamport safety property is a set of behaviours closed under all forms of **stuttering** (finite, anywhere in a behaviour, and infinite, at the end). In Alpern & Schneider's setting safety properties are those sets of behaviours closed under (a) **prefix** (similar to closure under infinite stuttering only) and **limits** (of sequences of behaviours that agree on ever longer prefixes).